# how to isolate backrefernce in c++ regex_replace

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("there is a subsequence in the string\n");
  std::regex e ("\\b(a )(subsequence)([^ ]*)");
  // with flags:
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"$11digit$3",std::regex_constants::format_default);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Where `$1` and `$2` are the back-references. The output of the above command:

```
there is digit in the string
```

But the output should be:

```
there is a 1digit in the string
```

It's obvious that $11 is taking it as 11th backreference, but I just want to append a `1` at the end of the backreference `$1`. How do I isoloate the `$1` so that I can put a digit after it.

I have tried to isolate it with `${1}`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Since there's a 2-digit limitation to `$` back-references, setting a replace string such as `"$011digit$3"` works. But I find it's more a hack than a real solution.

Comment: Thanks, @mamahuhu , I didn't think about that... It's a good workaround. I will just have to make sure that every backreference is of two digits...And you can put that as an answer, I will upvote you...